# Validating a specific postcode in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to validate a specific postcode in a form for a delivery website.

They are only delivering in Leeds so I need to validate postcodes to only allow  if the postcode starts with LS

How would I go about doing this?
Really need help as I don't have much of an idea on how to go about doing this

Comment: Would you please share some code? What have you tried? BTW try to have a look at javascript regular expression (regexp) to see how to check if a string matches a specific pattern

Comment: Your question is unclear and voted to close as such.

Answer (score 2):

Just test the first two characters:

```
if (substr($postcode, 0, 2) != "LS") {
    // report error
}
```

Comment: what if user enters `LSLS` ?

Comment: The OP said "only allow them to continue with the form if the postcode starts with LS". He didn't say anything about the rest.

Comment: The OP actually says they want the postcode validated AND only allow them to continue if it starts with LS. :|

Comment: It's ambiguous, that use of _and_ can be interpreted as clarifying how it validates them.

Comment: The question seems to be a runaway anyway. (2 Fred's in on thread, will you lookah dat). I voted to close as unclear. Plus, as per what the operative word here being "starts" with. So, this answer basically "answers" the question.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i'm only looking for the postcode to start with LS because That is the area code for Leeds

Comment: His point is that it might starts with `LS`, but the rest of it might not be a valid postcode.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find it best to look at using regular expressions to check the format of the postcode.
Regular expression can get quite complex but there are many free ones available on the numerous regex sites, just make sure you use one suitable for uk postcodes and then modify it to match text starting with only LS.

You can find an example of one [here](http://www.regxlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=260&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)